# Where is vsftpd.conf?

Tags: vsftpd

I have a 11.04 x86 server.

I ran `sudo apt-get install vsftpd` and that was successful. But I cannot find the `vsftpd.conf` file anywhere. I thought it was supposed to be in `/etc/vsftpd.conf`.

Comment: try this command `locate vsftpd.conf`

Comment: It's [supposed to be there](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/i386/vsftpd/filelist). What is the output of [`debsums -a vsftpd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/debsums.1.html)?

Comment: That finds me `/etc/init/vsftpd.conf`, which is the startup script for vsftpd. Should I just find the default conf file and put it in there myself?

Comment: `debsums` says: debsums: missing file /etc/vsftpd.conf (from vsftpd package)

Comment: If htorque can add an answer, I can accept it. The copy of the configuration file fixed my problem.

Comment: @Nik: it's not a clean solution and would only work if someone posted the configuration file. Could you remove (or rename) the configuration file (after stopping vsftpd) and try my solution? That is the way the system is supposed to work.

Answer (score 21):

You've a weird issue, try clearing you cache, update your repository information and install it again:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall vsftpd
```

If this did not work, purge vsftpd (remove it including its configuration files) and reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get purge vsftpd
sudo apt-get install vsftpd
```

Comment: The first procedure did not work. The purge/install worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.

Comment: Me the same , second worked !

Comment: Ten years later: The first procedure did not work. The purge/install worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like the installation didn't complete successfully. The quickest solution is probably going to be to reinstall vsftpd:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall vsftpd
```

Comment: That hasn't made the conf file show up.

Comment: Just installed it and it's there. Here it is: http://paste.ubuntu.com/619932/

Comment: I appreciate the copy of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party bu hope what I discovered is useful.

The file is not there after install. However

```
/etc/vstftd.conf
```

will be created after starting up the server.
It's installed with

```
sudo apt-get install vsftpd
```

and started with

```
sudo systemctl start vsftpd.service
```

This should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cat /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
```

That is where it is located for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. When I observed the installation log carefully, it turned out that the installation was stopping before re-installing the directory "srv/ftp". I deleted the directory ftp from /srv so that /srv was empty. Then I reinstalled and had my original vsftpd.conf script replaced in /etc/vsftpd.conf.

Comment: Uh. Be sure to inspect whether you want to delete `/srv`, as it may contain files you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure vsftpd
```

This will affect package's configuration and rerun some scripts designed for package proper operation.

Answer (score 0):

try this command :

```
sudo find . -type f -name vsftpd.conf|grep vsftpd.conf
```

it should find the file in ./etc/

if the file is not there, then try following command :

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall vsftpd
```

and then the find again -

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot find the `vsftpd.conf` under `/etc/vstftd.conf`, then you need to start `vsftpd` at least once.
This will create the config file afterwards

```
sudo systemctl start vsftpd.service
ls -lahG /etc
```