# vsftpd login incorrect issue

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I install vsftpd on my ubuntu server, this follow is my `vsftpd.conf` file:

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
check_shell=NO
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=ftp
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
```

Then I try login the ftp server on my mac:

```
$ ftp 162.243.78.240
Connected to 162.243.78.240.
220 (vsFTPd 2.3.5)
Name (162.243.78.240:tangmonk): demo
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
530 Login incorrect.
ftp: Login failed
```

the `demo` user's password is absolutely correct, But I don't know why `Login incorrect.`

Comment: Just a note, please consider using SFTP instead of FTP if you have the choice. It's also a lot easier setting up, usually, in addition to being more secure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: The principle reason for using vsftpd is eash chroot jail and using sftp is harder to do on different UNIX dialects.  In fact, the best way is through a thirdparty SFTP daemon made in the UK.

Answer (score 5):

1. Look at your **/etc/passwd** file
2. Find your user and look shell (example ttr:x:501:501::/home/ukraine/ttr:**/sbin/nologin**)
3. Add this shell (**/bin/false** or **/sbin/nologin**) to your **/etc/shell** or **/etc/shells**

After that, check your connection

> *Status:  Retrieving directory listing... Command:    PWD Response:   257 "/home/ukraine/ttr" Status: Directory listing successful*

Comment: Thanks for this info, I added a user which uses both `/sbin/nologin` and `/bin/bash`, I had to `userdel` then `sudo useradd -m -s /bin/bash user`so it can use only bash. It succeed to connect then

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry, well' solve in a blink! :-)
Follow my steps:

1. Edit your config file with the `nano` console text editor (or your preferred text editor) and add those lines:

   userlist_enable=YES

   local_enable=YES
2. **If** you receive errors about PAM insert or edit:

   pam_service_name=vsftpd
3. Edit `/etc/vsftpd/ftpusers` and **remove** your user.
4. Edit `/etc/vsftpd/user_list` and **remove** your user.

**Important note**: protect your ftp account **very** well and disable the anonymous login explicitly; I also suggest to use the chroot cage to prevent a user from wandering...
 Suggestions: `anonymous_enable=NO` , `chroot_local_user=YES`; doing so a remote intruder cannot escape from the home directory and an anoymous will not be able to access your server.

Have a nice experience,

please ask by commenting down here if you need more help and click the up arrow if I helped you.

Comment: Thanks your reply, I didn't have ```/etc/vsftpd``` directory, I try to use ```apt-get remove vsftpd``` and ```apt-get install vsftpd``` to reinstall vsftpd, But still not have ```/etc/vsftpd```

Comment: Then look for /etc/vsftpd.conf ; if you can't find it follow this topic: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47260/where-is-vsftpd-conf

Answer (score 0):

Just one possible cause: you did not set the password of ftp user "demo".

Use `passwd demo` to set it.

And I also saw some tutorials saying create a file under `/etc/vsftpd/` and use `db_load` to load it into a Berkeley .db file. It seems this doesn't work, the .db file makes no difference.