# Uninstall then install makes vstpd service unrecognized, vsftpd: unrecognized service

Tags: 14.04, server, ftp, vsftpd

I installed `vsftpd` on my server using [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/vsftpd) and [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-on-ubuntu-12-04) link. But due to [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22420177/500-oops-vsftpd-refusing-to-run-with-writable-root-inside-chroot-login-faile) I followed the solution and tried to update the `vsftpd`.
But because of some configuration problem it was not functioning and I decided to reinstall it using [this problem's solutions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47260/where-is-vsftpd-conf).
But now after installing it again when I type:

`sudo service vsftpd restart` or `sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart` it shows me:

```
vsftpd: unrecognized service. and
sudo: /etc/init.d/vsftpd: command not found
```

How to solve this?

Comment: It looks like it isn't actually installed. Try `sudo apt-get purge vsftpd && sudo apt-get install vsftpd`

Comment: I did as you said, but the result is same.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

There currently is a [kernel bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vsftpd/+bug/1313450) in 14.04 that will be solved by a kernel update.  My current kernel is: `3.13.0-34-generic`, and the minimum needed kernel version at the time of this writing is: `3.15.0-031500`.

**Workaround**

This is **not** a *solution* to the problem, but will allow you to run `vsftp` and will allow you to stop `vsftp` by rebooting until a solution to the kernel problem is deployed to Ubuntu 14.04

*To start vsftpd:*

Edit the `/etc/vsftpd.conf` and set the `listen=` parameter to `YES`

```
sudo reboot
```

`vsftp` will get started as a standalone program (not a service)

*To stop vsftpd:*

Edit the `/etc/vsftpd.conf` and set the `listen=` parameter to `NO`

```
sudo reboot
```

If anyone has any better ideas then mine, feel free to add to this answer!!!